# CodedUI TestCaseFilter

Tags: filter, datasource, coded-ui-tests, datarow

I'm using a CSV file as a DataSource in my CodedUI tests.  The file looks like so:

Environment,URL
Live,www.example.com
Stage,stage.example.com
 
Test,test.example.com

I'd like to be able to setup my TestCaseFilter to selectively run the tests on only one of the environments when running the vstest.console.exe commandline.  I can't seem to find any way to do that, i.e. it looks like the TestCaseFilter commandline parameter only supports specific properties.  Am I wrong?  Is there a way to pass a custom property to TestCaseFilter so that only the tests that pertain to a specific DataRow are executed?

The DataSource in my tests is setup like so:
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\environments.csv", "environments#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

And I am referencing the environment in each test like so:
var url = TestContext.DataRow["URL"].ToString();

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, do you mean that you want to run only one row that you want to where there a re 3 rows in testdata file?

Comment: How do u want to specify the row that you want to run? In the test method or in excel itself?

Answer (score 0):

The simple and best way is to add another column next to the environment column in your testdata file. Say the column name is RunStatus. The values should either be 'Yes' or 'No', the logic is that the URL which has Runstatus as Yes should be included for the execution.
[image]

Before the TestMethod, have a condition to check the Runstatus of the row is Yes. If it's Yes, then Run the TestMethod.

```
[TestMethod]
public void RunTheTest(TestContext testcontext)
{
   if(testcontext.DataRow["RunStatus"].ToString()=="Yes")
   {
    TestMethod1();
   }
}
```

Hope it helps. Good luck !!